# While playing with istio I have renamed the Bookinfo sample’s services and now it stopped working

Tags: istio

We have deployed the bookinfo sample application on our cluster as means of making sure istio is working correctly and to demo it’s capabilities.

Due to company’s policies we had to change the service names to follow standard convention:

```
details —> xx-bookinfodetails-app
ratings —> xx-bookinforatings-app
productpage —> xx-bookinfoproductpage-app
reviews (all versions) —> xx-bookinforeviews-app
```

We have created a gateway and virtualService to route traffic to the first service ProductPage, which in turn is looking for other services (details/reviews) but now the application is “broken” since it is looking for http://details:9080 and http://reviews:9080 but now they don’t exist anymore.

I am new to istio and don’t know how to solve this and create some form of “translation or rewrite” so that internal requests to http://details would be actually forwarded to http://xx-bookinfodetails-app:9080.
I was trying playing with the productpage virtualservice, also tried creating virtualservices for details and reviews.
I’ve tried creating Destination (though not really knowing what would it help with).
I see that there’s something called ServiceEntry but I cannot find any example to handle internal traffic and quite frankly I didn’t really understand when to use SE.

Help would be highly appreciated
Udi

Comment: Hi, changing names is not a simple task. Did You refactor all the labels and other metadata that might be referencing in all the `yaml` files? The applications images might also reference other services by predefined service names.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks for commenting.
I have intentionally changed only service names, and therefore the problem mentioned above.
So to summarize, how can I trick an application looking for a certain host name (http://details) to actually transfer the request to a different service name (http://xx-bookinfodetails-xxx).
I've been trying to understand the concept of ServiceEntry (because it seems to be that specific item) but cannot find any decent data.

Comment: `ServiceEntry` object is used to introduce external service (not in istio mesh) to the service registry so it can be used with istio. In Your case tricking application to route to other service would require set of rewrites in Your `VirtualService`.